# square-free word

Tags: formal-languages, binary, regular-language

I am trying to understand one concept. Is it possible to have a square-free(no subwords ss) word in a language of just $\{0,1\}$ of any given length ( $10^{100}$ for instance). I found out a Thue–Morse sequence , but it is still not really the thing. If there is no such word , how to prove it?

Comment: yes consider $01001000100001....$ (once zero, one, twice zero, one, triple zero...)

Comment: @Yanko but , isn't 00 a subword?

Comment: It is, what is your definition for square-free? I understand it as "a word $w$ is square free if there is no sub-word $s$ such that $w=ss$" Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you can't have $00$ and $11$ then the only possible sequences are $010101..$ or $101010..$ which are not square-free.

Comment: @Yanko ok, I mean that 10101 is not square-free.It is all about a complete language with any sequence of 0-s and 1-s

Comment: I don't understand. Can you provide a formal definition for "square-free"?

Comment: @Yanko Word is considered a not square free , if it has a subword ss, where $s \neq \varepsilon$

Comment: [Square-free word definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word).

Comment: Is there a square-free word of lenth $4$? If there is no square-free word of length $4$, how can there be a square-free word of length $10^{100}$?

Comment: @bof yes  ,for example $1001$

Comment: But that has $00$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longest square-free word for a language with a binary alphabet is of length 3. However, for alphabets of at least three symbols, there are infinitely many square-free words.

It's easy to prove the first assertion simply by enumerating all binary sequences of length four and observing that all of them contain a square. Since every word of length greater than four contains a subword of length 4, it must also contain a square (the one in the subword, at least).

Comment: For an alphabet of $3$ symbols, there are infinitely many square-free words — equivalently, there is an infinitely long square-free word.

Comment: @bof: i feel like the word "equivalently" is doing an awful lot of work there, since once you admit the existence of infinite strings, you may be in a different calculus. But, ok.